# Ruby on Rails, how to make image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, tags

I am trying to put image and when I click on image to go for example in for_rent_index_path ( witch in views)
 for example I have this :

```
 `<%= link_to "For rent", forrent_index_path %><br/>`
```

and works but is without image. I want to remove this and put an image with tag

how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the image tag as the first param in link to.

```
 <%= link_to (image_tag "image.jpg"), forrent_index_path %><br/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("image.jpg", :alt => "image", :width => 50, :height => 50, :title => "Click here") forrent_index_path) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
link_to image_tag('/images/image.png') + "some text", url_for({:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'}), :class => 'some class', :remote => true %>
```